# Specify information that populates box when pasting URL into LinkedIn

Tags: share, linkedin-api

When I paste a URL into the "What should your network know?" box (similar to the Facebook's status box), it pulls data from my site, and populates a box below with a Title, URL, an a bit of text.

The text it's pulling, though, is from my right rail of events, not the main article.

Is there a way to specify or let it know what info you think it should pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn also supports a subset of the Open Graph tags used by Facebook to provide metadata about the page.  This is documented here:
    https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares

Note, however, that the LinkedIn scraper caches page data when a page is shared. It is supposed to re-scrape pages every week to look for more information beyond what's in the cache, but the re-scraping is not currently (as of late April 2012) working correctly - this means you need to change the page name or try cache-busting with fake query parameters to get it to re-read your page.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to pull the title from an `<h1>` on the page.

Originally it was pulling from the **last** `<h1>` on the page - when I removed that, it retrieved the title from the **first** `<h1>` on the page.

Neither of those were correct, so I continued removing `<h1>` tags until the only one left was the actual title of the article (**which is how it should have been anyway**), and it worked.

After this change, it pulled the correct title AND text (the first bit of text not wrapped in a header tag immediately following my `<h1>` article title).